# Possible to pipe into an if-statement?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script that outputs about 10 lines every time if it run. The content of these lines varies.

I would really like to be able to `grep` in the output and do different things depending on the output.

In pseudo this is what I would like to do

```
cat /etc/password | \\
if [ grep "root" $STDOUT ]; then
   echo "root is found"

elif [ grep "nobody" $STDOUT ]; then
   echo "nobody is found"

fi
```

Here have I used `cat /etc/password` as an example, but it should be replaced with my scripts mentioned above.

The problem is, how do I get hold of the output from `cat /etc/password` in the `if`/`elif` conditions?

Comment: Maybe awk or perl are better suited for your task..

Comment: don't use `cat` if the intent is not either displaying or concatenating. Here you can just give the file in the grep command line, because it is accepted, else you can just redirect the file (`<`).

Comment: You don't need line continuation after `|`, `&&` and `||`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Benoit recommends, just use `grep` directly.

As @larsmans notes, you can avoid a double-read of the file by reading it into a variable once.

Given the availability of `bash` I'd do it like this:

```
password=$(< /etc/passwd)

if grep -q root <<< "$password" ; then
    echo root found
elif grep -q nobody <<< "$password" ; then
    echo nobody found
fi
```

One read of the file, one or two invocations of `grep`, no other processes or subshells launched.

Comment: Very interesting solution. Why do you have `IFS=` on the first line?

Comment: In bash, you can just say `password=$(< /etc/passwd)`

Comment: @SandraSchlichting: Habit, mostly. It's something I do reflexively when using `read` and not wanting input to be split, though it wasn't needed here.

Comment: If you are just looking for static strings, you could use `case` instead of `grep` - no external processes at all!

Comment: If you want to get really accurate you should use `if getent passwd root >/dev/null ; then ... fi` but I suppose few people really care to do this right.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest using awk:

```
cat /etc/passwd | awk '/root/{ do something }/nobody/{ do something else }'
```

You can achieve the same in bash using an expression like:

```
cat /etc/passwd |
while read; do
  if echo "$REPLY" | fgrep root; then
    something
  fi
  if echo "$REPLY" | fgrep nobody; then
    something_else
  fi
done
```

However the pure bash solution is less efficient for large inputs because it runs separate instances of `grep` for every line.

Comment: Don't use `cat` like that,  you can pass `passwd` directly to `awk`, `while`, etc..

Comment: True, but it's often more readable this way because the data source is in the front, and for parsing a few dozen lines performance is really not an issue. At this scale it's just a matter of personal preference and not a reason to vote down.

Answer (score 4):

You just do :

```
if grep -q "root" /etc/passwd ; then
   ...
fi
```

which will play the `...` commands if grep exit code is 0.

remember that [`\[` is a external command](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?test), probably located in `/usr/bin/[` (normally it's a hard link to `test` and when invoked as `[` it requires a matching `]` argument). Also see the [pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) page here, many of them deal are related to that command.

Comment: +1, but you might want to add `-q` to `grep` to suppress output.

Answer (score 3):

Piping into an if-statement is possible with subshells, but that solution will break since you're running two `grep` commands on the pipe, the first of which will exhaust it.

The best solution in your case is probably to read `/etc/passwd` into a variable, then `grep` it:

```
passwd=$(cat /etc/passwd)
if (echo $passwd | grep -q root); then
     echo "root found"
fi
if (echo $passwd | grep -q nobody); then
     echo "nobody found"
fi
```

Comment: It's cheaper to say `IFS= read -r -d '' password</etc/passwd` to read the file contents into a variable.

Comment: Ok, but I don't see how that warrants a -1.

Comment: It doesn't. I don't know who did that, but I've counter-voted in outrage.

Answer (score 1):

Just use &&:

```
grep -q root /etc/password && echo "root is found"

grep -q nobody /etc/password && echo "nobody is found"
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z $1 ]; then
   echo Usage: $0 [UID to search for]
   exit 1;
fi

SEARCHID="$1"

function notFound() {
    echo NOT FOUND 
}

function found() {
    echo Found it
}

function main() {

    grep -i $SEARCHID /etc/passwd
    # Move $? to a variable 
    SEARCHRESULT=$?

    if [ "$SEARCHRESULT" != "0" ]; then
       notFound;
    else
       found;
    fi
}

# call main function
main
```

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, you could use a temporary file.

```
t=$(mktemp -t passwd.XXXXXXXX)
trap 'rm $t' 0
trap 'exit 127' 1 2 3 5 15
cat >$t
for u in root nobody; do
  fgrep $u $t
done
```

The `trap`s are to remove the temporary file afterwards.

As an aside, you *can* pipe to an `if`, but the first `grep`inside your conditional would already consume all of its standard input. It's more useful in situations like this:

```
if $option_count ; then
    wc -l
else
    tac
fi <file
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple example for `pipe` to statement without `if` keyword :

```
echo -e hello | [ $(cat) == hello ] && echo "Ok"
```

with `else` too easy :

```
echo -e hello | ([ $(cat) == 'bye' ] && echo "Ok" || echo "No Okey")
```

For example you want to check status code of http response is equal to 200 or not :

```
curl http://google.com -w "%{http_code}" -s -o /dev/null | [ $(cat) == 200 ] && echo "Request successful processed"
# Note: in this example google response is 403 .
```